# Выравнивание сетки товаров woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, выравнивание

помогите пожалуйста выровнить сетку товаров в woocommerce.
Вот здесь видно что не ровно отображаются товары из-за длинного названия.
http://mixapple.ru/product-category/apple/?filter_model=iphone-6s

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать фиксированную высоту описанию товара:

```
h4.entry-title {
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```